# Magento 2.4 - Composer php 7.4 error magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework

Tags: php, composer, php-7, magento2.4

We run Magento 2.4 with php7.4, that should be supported. But we get the following error when we try to update a module using composer:

```
magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 2.6.5 requires php ~7.1.0||~7.2.0||~7.3.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.7) does not satisfy that requirement.

Installation request for magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework (locked at 2.6.5, required as ~2.6.4) -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[2.6.5]
```

How can we solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update to "~3.1.0".
You can get list of available versions like this

```
composer show magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.*.* --all | grep -m 1 versions
```

Comment: Thanks, but when we run the composer update command, there is not update available. And why is this module not updated by Magneto when we update to 2.4?

Comment: In composer.json set it like this
`"magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "~3.1.0" `,
And run `composer update`.

Comment: Thanks, but than we get: `magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.1.0 requires symfony/finder ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/finder[v5.0.0, v5.0.1, v5.0.10, v5.0.11, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.0.9, v5.1.0, v5.1.1, v5.1.2, v5.1.3, v5.1.4, v5.1.5]. - Conclusion: don't install symfony/finder v5.0.1`

Comment: its not work for me

Answer (score 2):

if you look at magento 2.4 open source composer files, you will find

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/445b0f1a3d6a91b5da32d311077c2112ef0b1503/composer.json#L117

so try 3.0 version

Answer (score 1):

there are few changes that you need to do in your composer.json
Me helped: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29350#issuecomment-751921479